# Can't change webmin port on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, centos6, webmin

I have a CentOS 6.5 with webmin installed. I need to change the default port (10000) to something else (1020) for example.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. From web interface I changed the port and when it redirect to the address with the new port all I get is "*This webpage is not available*".
2. From command line I've changed the file `miniserv.conf` and added the port I want, I add the new rule to the iptables and after I restart webmin and iptable all I get is "*This webpage is not available*".

PS: In another server running CentOS 5.8 it works from interface and command line.

Comment: It's working for me on CentOS 6.5 with Webmin 1.700

Comment: Is it configured to run over https?

Comment: @CélineAussourd yes mine is configured to redirect to HTTPS and webmin only runs over HTTPS. For the short term, I limited connections only from my IP because I couldn't get the port changed.

Comment: Silly question but, Did you check all your firewalls?

Comment: Also, In the future, please user SuperUser for these types of questions.

Comment: After you make the change, does `netstat -plnt` show webmin using the port you specified?

Comment: This question should be on Superuser and not Stackoverflow. Here it is off-topic

Comment: do you run webmin via xinetd. in this case you have to change  /etc/xinetd.conf

Comment: Did you check your firewall configuration? Maybe the new port is blocked.